# Need a regular expression to match three character strings

Tags: regex

I generally stay away from `regular expressions` because I seldom find a good use for them. But in this case, I don't think I have choice.

I need a regex for the following situation.  I will be looking at three character strings. It will be a match if the first character is `1-9 or the letters o,n,d (lower or upper)`  AND the second character is `1,2 or 3` and the third character is `0-9`.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: You should really learn to use regular expressions.  They are super-useful.

Comment: I second Kip's response.  Oddly enough, the more you learn about them, the more useful they become.

Comment: Could you edit the title of your question to be a little more descriptive?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would vote Kip's comment up if it would be possible. Regex (and pattern matching in general) is a sharp, powerful tool. Any time spent studying them it's well worth it!

Comment: Yes, please edit the title as suggested, and then remove the pointless text from the question about how you don't understand regex.

Comment: The only way someone doesn't find regexes useful is because one doesn't know them.  I use regexes in searches about half of the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slight variation on a few other answers.  Restrict the input to be exactly the matched text.

```
^[1-9ondOND][123][0-9]$
```

Comment: Instead of the `^` and `$` anchors, the OP might also find `\W` or `\s` useful on each end of the expression.  `\W` is a non-word character (`\w` is its opposite and matches letters and numbers), and `\s` matches any whitespace character (similarly, `\S` matches non whitespace characters).

Answer (score 5):

```
[1-9ondOND][123][0-9]
```

I omitted the `^` and `$` (beginning and end of string markers) because you said you'd have three-character strings, but there's no harm in including them, and they may improve speed, not that that'll be a big deal on such short input.

Of course, this assumes you're working in a language and locale where the uppercase equivalent of `o`, `n`, and `d` are `O`, `N`, and `D`. If not, you'll need to tell your regex interpreter to ignore case. The mechanism varies by language/framework.

For python, you'd use something like:

```
re.match('[1-9ond][123][0-9]', inputstring, re.IGNORECASE)
```

The `re.match` forces a match at the beginning of string, so you wouldn't need the `^` in any case.

Comment: Even better to include the IGNORECASE directive in the re itself: '(?i)[1-9ond][123][0-9]', possibly with the addition of "^" and "$" in their respective places: '(?i)^[1-9ond][123][0-9]$'

Comment: I'm intrigued. Why better? So one doesn't have to learn how to do it on various platforms? I like the explicitness of re.IGNORECASE, but I realize that's just my taste... I'm keen to learn the advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Perl RegEx: `/^[1-9ondOND][1-3][0-9]$/`

`^` at the start of the string;
`$` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
[1-9ond][123][0-9]
```

[Here's a useful place to test your RegEx.](http://web.archive.org/web/20151030080919/http://osteele.com:80/tools/rework/)

Comment: @Greg This regex won't work if the first character is `upper case` letter

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but hope this will help

```
([1-9]|(?i)(o|n|d))[123][\d]
```

http://regex101.com/r/vE2jT1/1

Answer (score -2):

In a PREG-based system (most of them these days):

```
^(?:[1-9]|[ond])[1-3][0-9]$
```

Some systems require the start/end markers (PHP, Perl, but not .NET for instance), if yours does, it'd end up something like:

```
/^(?:[1-9]|[ond])[1-3][0-9]$/
```

Comment: ...and not even correct since it doesn't handle case in-sensitivity.

Comment: The best way of handling case insensitivity is in regex options (`/i` typically, or with the appropriate flag in .NET, or...), not the regex itself.